# How can get the json data automatically instead of copy and paste manually?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to get the json data in the target url:
[target url](https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json?page=1&size=300)

To get it manually :open it in brower manually and copy,paste.I want a more samrt way--programmatically and automatically,have tried with several way,all failed.
Method 1--traditional way with wget or curl:

```
wget  https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json?page=1&size=300
--2021-02-09 11:55:44--  https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json?page=1
Resolving xueqiu.com (xueqiu.com)... 39.96.249.191
Connecting to xueqiu.com (xueqiu.com)|39.96.249.191|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-02-09 11:55:44 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Method 2--scrapy with selenium:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> url="https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json?page=1&size=300"
>>> browser.get(url)
```

It happen to me in the browser:

```
{"error_description":"遇到错误，请刷新页面或者重新登录帐号后再试","error_uri":"/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json","error_code":"400016"}
```

Method 3--build a mitmproxy:

```
mitmweb   --listen-host  127.0.0.1  -p  8080
```

Set proxy in browser and open the target url in browser

Error info in terminal:

```
Web server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Opening in existing browser session.
Proxy server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
127.0.0.1:41268: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:41270: clientconnect
127.0.0.1:41268: HTTP/2 connection terminated by client: error code: 0, last stream id: 0, additional data: None
```

Error info in browser:

```
error_description   "遇到错误，请刷新页面或者重新登录帐号后再试"
error_uri   "/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json"
error_code  "400016"
```

So powerful site to protect the data ,is there no way to get the data automatically?

Comment: Any kind of authentication? I can't even access the url in a browser manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module

```
import json

import requests
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0",}
import requests

cookies = {
    'xq_a_token': '176b14b3953a7c8a2ae4e4fae4c848decc03a883',
    'xqat': '176b14b3953a7c8a2ae4e4fae4c848decc03a883',
    'xq_r_token': '2c9b0faa98159f39fa3f96606a9498edb9ddac60',
    'xq_id_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1aWQiOi0xLCJpc3MiOiJ1YyIsImV4cCI6MTYxMzQ0MzE3MSwiY3RtIjoxNjEyODQ5MDY2ODI3LCJjaWQiOiJkOWQwbjRBWnVwIn0.VuyNicSjIvVkp9FrCzIlRyx8487XM4HH1C3X9KsFA2FipFiilSifBhux9pMNRyziHHiEifhX-xOgccc8IG1mn8cOylOVy3b-L1YG2T5Hs8MKgx7qm4gnV5Mzm_5_G5BiNtO44aczUcmp0g53dp7-0_Bvw3RlwXzT1DTvCKTV-s_zfBsOPyFTfiqyDUxU-oBRvkz1GpgVJzJL4EmZ8zDE2PBqeW00ueLLC7qPW50WeDCsEFS4ZPAvd2SbX9JPk-lU2WzlcMck2S9iFYmpDwuTeQuPbSeSl6jt5suwTImSgJDIUP9o2TX_Z7nNRDTYxvbP8XlejSt8X0pRDPDd_zpbMQ',
    'u': '661612849116563',
    'device_id': '24700f9f1986800ab4fcc880530dd0ed',
    'Hm_lvt_1db88642e346389874251b5a1eded6e3': '1612849123',
    's': 'c111f3y1kn',
    'Hm_lpvt_1db88642e346389874251b5a1eded6e3': '1612849252',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'no-cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'image',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referer': '',
}

params = (
    ('page', '1'),
    ('size', '300'),
)

response = requests.get('https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code)
json_data = response.json()
print(json_data)
```

Comment: It is half-automatically ,how can get the cookie automatically?Open the webpage and save cookie automatically instead of manually?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `scrapy`:

```
import json

import scrapy


class StockSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stock_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://xueqiu.com/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json?page=1&size=300']
    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.16; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0',
            'Host': 'xueqiu.com',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,br',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Referer': '',
        },
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False
    }
    handle_httpstatus_list = [400]

    def parse(self, response):
        json_result = json.loads(response.body)
        yield json_result
```

Run spider: `scrapy crawl stock_spider`

Comment: {'error_description': '遇到错误，请刷新页面或者重新登录帐号后再试', 'error_uri': '/stock/cata/stocktypelist.json', 'error_code': '400016'}